# Capture and display filters in wireshark (limit destination IP)?

Tags: wireshark

In Wireshark I can successfully create this display filter that will only show traffic going to `x.x.x.x`

```
ip.dst==x.x.x.x
```

But how do I create a corresponding capture filter?

E.g. if I remove all display filters and add this capture filter:

```
ip host x.x.x.x
```

and then restart the capture I still see tons of other destination IPs.

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to limit destination IP for a *capture* filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the filter `ip host x.x.x.x` is not correct. Wireshark accept it, but it seems it take into account only `ip`

`host x.x.x.x` match either source or destination IP address x.x.x.x (useful to see traffic sent and received by an host, since most network communication are bi-directional).

If you want only destination host you should use `dst host x.x.x.x`